# How should my flagging change when I gain the ability to vote to close?

Tags: discussion, faq, flagging, vote-to-close

My rep is going to reach 3,000 soon (2,987 at the time of this post), so I should be able to vote to close soon.  How should my flagging habits change when I gain this ability?  What should I do when I encounter a post that:

1. is off topic and should be migrated to a site for which there is a migration path?
2. is off topic and should be migrated to a site not listed in the vote-to-close dialog?
3. is off topic and should not be migrated?
4. should be closed for some other reason?
5. requires a moderator action other than closing, such as deletion?
6. is spam or offensive?

When should I use a flag, vote to close, or do both?

Comment: Side note: the flag dialog will automatically convert the "it doesn't belong here" flag dialog to the vote-to-close dialog once you reach 3k. That being said, it's fewer clicks just to choose `close` in the first place.

Comment: `Good idea` and `thank you` to whomever thought of including a link to this question for those who achieve "vote to close" status. I just got "vote to close" priveledges (although I can't spell privledges... priviledges... privilegdes) on Literature beta SE and that's how I got here.

Comment: @DragonLord I'm *pretty sure* you've heard about it, mainly because you corrected my spelling. But for those who don't know, it's the fact that non-moderators who hold a gold badge of a tag that the initial revision of the post contained can bindingly close that question as a duplicate and bindingly reopen any such post that is closed as a duplicate, so long as they have >= 3k reputation.

Comment: Great post and +1 for what @EllieKesselman said, but shouldn't this question itself be moved to Meta SE?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

> #### 1: … is off topic and should be migrated to a site for which there is a migration path?

Vote to close as off-topic as "belongs on another site".

> #### 2: … is off topic and should be migrated to a site not listed in the vote-to-close dialog?

Vote to close as off-topic *and* flag for ♦ moderator attention using the free-text box.
This ensures that even if we don't believe the migration is warranted that you will at least still be helping to close an off-topic question.

Make sure the question is off-topic here, on-topic there *and* good quality before taking action – if it's not all three of these things we won't even consider migration.

> #### 3: … is off topic and should not be migrated?

Vote to close as off-topic as "off-topic".

> #### 4: … should be closed for some other reason?

Vote to close using the relevant close reason.

If none of the reasons fit then consider if it really does need closing, and maybe flag for a ♦ using the free-text flag if you believe there is a case for doing so.

> #### 5: … requires a moderator action other than closing, such as deletion?

If it's something the community can do first (edit to fix problems, flag spam, close, etc) then that route should be taken first.

If that fails, it's something the community cannot handle or the problem is urgent then please flag for ♦ moderator attention and use the free-text flag.

> #### 6: … is spam or offensive?

Flag as spam or offensive.

---

Note that even if a question is old and does not receive much attention, casting a close vote will [put it into a review queue](https://superuser.com/review/close). Other users can work through the queue by casting their own votes or deciding to leave the question open. This means there is **no need to flag old questions** for moderator attention anymore.

Comment: Does the last paragraph still apply with `/review` and its *close* tab? What are examples of urgent problems that warrant moderator flags?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'd say it's probably less important, but still a little bit relevant (as we are likely to have more closers than reviewers, although I've no numbers to support this assumption). And as for "urgent", well, I'm not actually sure... it's been a while since I wrote this.

Comment: Since the queues have been working quite efficiently and any close vote cast on old questions will be picked up rather fast, there's no need to flag those. I therefore removed the last paragraph. Haven't come across anything *urgent* either, so if something's wrong, people will flag the question anyway, I suppose.