# Flag weight doesn't grow up any more after crossing 3000 reputation

Tags: support, flagging, vote-to-close, flag-weight

I've now got 3k reputation, acquiring the "cast close and reopen questions" privilege.

Since then, I don't know if any of my flags to close questions have been marked valid or not as my flag weight has not changed since then.

Is this right?  Do I no longer gain or lose flag weight?

Comment: Closing this because flag weight is no longer a visible statistic (leaving this question no longer relevant) and it's purpose has changed slightly since the time that is was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Above a flag weight score of **500** the increase with each flag accepted as helpful becomes non-linear, with an upper limit of 750.

This effect is unrelated to your reputation score.

The MSO [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page [What is flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) should confirm this, with the original source being [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117).

However, the flag weight not changing despite your continued flagging is based on what option you're flagging as and your reputation.

As a user with 3000 reputation, when you flag a question to be closed, it will automatically convert it to a vote to close and thus not a flag. This is by design.

You can still flag non-answers, spam and abusive posts as before.

If it's an urgent matter, or requires moderator intervention (such as migration to a site not included in the default options), use the flag **other** and include a short precis on what the situation is.

Comment: So, I've been flagging questions for all this week, even when they are closed or not, my flag weight is freeze at 599.3514 for more than 3 days. It doesn't change anyway. May in my case it is bugged???

Comment: Looking at your [flag list](http://superuser.com/users/flag-weight/79358) (private to you and ♦s) it looks like you haven't flagged anything for two days, of course it isn't going to change.

Comment: Actually when I flag something it will direct cast it as "close", even when I click on "Flag" the question.... This is correct? I mean, this way i will never get flag weight any more.

Comment: That's because at 3k you can *vote* to close now, so you should only flag if the situation is really *urgent* or is something that can only be handled by a moderator. You can still flag spam, non-answers, abusive posts, and so on, as you could before.

Comment: @Diogo_Rocha - if it is really urgent you can vote to close *and* flag it. Best of both worlds.

Comment: You might find [this post here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154) helpful, it was our response to another user with respect to how they should flag after surpassing 3k.

Comment: I tried to vote to close and then flag it, however when I tried to flag, the option "it doent bellong here" were unavaiable...

Comment: @DMA57361 - It means i will cant flag to close the question anymore??? Just in cases such as exact duplicate or anything else?

Comment: @Diogo, you can always flag with the "other" type, but again, if the question can be closed you should vote to close (all the options you used to have are under close, as before). Only flag for closure if it is *urgent* or needs special treatment (such as migration to an unusual site).

Comment: Sure, I understand, thank you for clarifications :D

Comment: as of April 25 2012 the link to "What is flag weight" is broken

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver that is because flag weight is no longer visible to users or ♦ (you can see how many flags were taken as helpful/declined/etc still) and I believe plays a lesser role than it did previously, so I presume the FAQ pages were removed because they are no longer relevant to "the public" on the network.