# Why did slhck close this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I was going over the main page and found the question [Free batch image watermarking software](https://superuser.com/questions/40019/free-batch-image-watermarking-software) from 09'. The question is well formed and is on topic from what I can tell.

What was wrong with this question that caused it to be closed?

Comment: It's asking for software recommendations. See [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3515/since-when-are-software-recommendations-off-topic) or [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3510/recommendations-for-the-best).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Over the last months (years?), we've definitely changed our minds and raised our bar when it comes to shopping (or product) recommendations.

> I'm looking for a simple yet effective software to watermark a lot of photos in batch.

This is definitely one of these. The questions we'd have to ask are: *Which batch resizing tools have you tried?* or *Where are you stuck?* – none of which are actually answered here, so there is no research effort shown, at all.

The question goes on with a seemingly endless list of product recommendations, which is a great indicator of it being not constructive.

Oh, and it had 5 spam answers deleted too.

Finally, if we ever want to actually teach new users that we don't accept these kinds of questions anymore, we'll have to close them. Otherwise, people will be dragging them out and tell us that there are similar questions that weren't closed.

See also, in no particular order:

- [Suggestions for updating our FAQ](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5057/suggestions-for-updating-our-faq/5059#5059)
- [Since when are software recommendations off-topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3515/since-when-are-software-recommendations-off-topic)
- [Recommendations for the BEST?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3510/recommendations-for-the-best)

Comment: Just to be clear, I agree with @slhck's decision

Comment: @IvoFlipse as do I now that I had it explained. I was not demanding it to be re-opened, I wanted to learn why it was closed.

Comment: I know @ScottChamberlain, but to some it may not be apparently clear that if the other mods don't show their support, that it means they don't agree. Even though its the opposite: if the other mods don't show their disagreement, assume we agree. :-)

Comment: The real answer is that slhck beat the other mods and users to closing it

Comment: @random I'm sure there are one or two `software-rec` topics left for you to close.