# Question closed for offtopic, does not make sense

Tags: discussion

Closed (-2 votes):
https://superuser.com/questions/461215/ultra-deep-fractal-viewer

Not closed (+7 votes):
[Good fractal visualizer](https://superuser.com/questions/133641/good-fractal-visualizer)

May I hear the logic in that? The both questions are basically the same, except I asked for even better program.

Comment: Please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software Additionally, just because another question **wasn't** closed, doesn't mean yours should not be closed either. Sometimes questions slip the cracks.

Answer (score 2):

Votes are assigned by community members and don't reflect any kind of moderation policy. The other topic was posted in 2010 when we were much more tolerant, and these kinds of questions were much more popular with regular users as well.

Rules changed over time, and we're enforcing them more strictly than a few years ago. That one question slipped through the cracks is not sufficient reason to try again.

The [top section of the FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions) prohibits questions asking for *shopping and buying recommendations*, which includes *product* recommendations — something your question does. [We're in the process of improving that part of the FAQ](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5057/suggestions-for-updating-our-faq).

For information on how to ask these kinds of questions instead, see [this meta topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software).

Comment: Half of the questions are recommendations here. So what can we actually ask here? About problems using specific software? I could cloak my question under those terms though, and then someone will answer: "hey, dont try with that, use this", So whats the point?

Comment: @Rookie Most new questions state a problem and ask for a solution. In many cases, users didn't actually need new software, but just need to learn how to use what they have. These solutions can be posted to questions rephrased in terms of a problem, or a goal. We had tons of question about "Your favorite RSS reader/pixel editor/operating system/troubleshooting tool/..." (with answerers who didn't even bother to read the full Q), a pointless waste of time just showing how necessary the change in policy was. [Related blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: I dont think my question is "shopping", as that blog post explains. I didnt ask "best" of something, i simply asked a program to do a task. Same if i asked a program to control cookies, like my previous question was about. And many more questions i have asked for a program of some kind for a solution.