# I believe my question was unfairly closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I cannot understand my mistake, and now feel discouraged to try solving my issue with the help of community.

The question is this: [How can I constantly monitor if my server has network traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/526019/monitor-specific-program-network-activity)

I'm ready to agree that the question was poorly formulated or unclear, but not off-topic. I have asked for explanation in the comment, mentioning the person who closed first. No reaction from his side. What do I do?

Comment: your question was closed because it's asking for a product recommendation. Also absent is lack of research. See [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372) & [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Also, close voters, unless they edit the post, are not informed of your comments.

Comment: software-recommendation is quite an often case, there is a tag for that. I agree I didn`t demonstrate my research, but for that we have a "non-constructive" closing, don`t we?

Anyway, should I try somehow defending and reviving the question, or should I just reformulate it and post as a new one?

Comment: Product recommendations are offtopic, not just non-constructive. You should edit your post & Click on flag -> " it needs ♦ moderator attention" - > mention you'd like to reopen so that it can be checked by Moderators to see if it can be reopened.

Comment: Thank you @Sathya. However, if software-recommendation is off-topic, why isn't it stated in http://superuser.com/faq , to which off-topic disclaimer is pointing?

Comment: It's covered by the ([somewhat misleading](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions)) *shopping or buying recommendation* clause, which covers *product recommendations* in general. [This rule will probably be rephrased soon(ish)](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5059).

Comment: It should be rephrased, because for many people, especially FOSS fans, software has little to do with shopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you gave us a real problem to work with, this question is now specific enough so as (hopefully) not to end up in an endless list of answers with network monitoring tools. In essence: Ask about the problem you have and what you need solved, let those who answer figure out how to do it. There's not always a magic program that does everything one asks for.

It'd help if you mentioned a few tools you already know and why they don't work for your case, but I've reopened the question for now.

Note that this doesn't prevent others from voting to close again, as it's more of a borderline case.